# SSIS (2008R2) import from mssql to mysql failing due to a date column

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc

I have an oledb connection to mssql and an ado.net destination (with odbc driver used) to mysql.  The tables are exectly the same and all the columns are working bar one.

The error message received is:
[ADO NET Destination [325]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Char[]'.

I've seen similar questions on other data types but the resolution of changing to string does not work here.  If I convert to string (has to be length 29 otherwise the conversion step fails) I get the following error message:

[ADO NET Destination [325]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.15]Incorrect datetime value: '2011-03-21 11:23:48.573000000' for column 'LastModificationDate' at row 1

Other potentially relevant details:
connection driver- {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}
script run before dataflow - set sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ANSI_QUOTES'
Other datetime columns are working
This column has a reasonably high proportion of nulls
mssql spec: [LastModificationDate] [datetime] NULL
mysql spec:  `LastModificationDate` datetime  NULL

Has anyone had experience with this issue and could provide some advice on resolving it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try converting it to string on sql server side in your query using:

```
convert(char(10),LastModificationDate,111)+' '+convert(char(8),LastModificationDate,108)
```

This works for me all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same big headache this week. I tried many ways. Thanks God, finnally, one of them worked. Hope it could help you a little bit.

For some columns with the data type of Int, datetime, decimal....,here, I identified as ColumnA, and I used it as datetime type.

1.in Data Flow Source, use SQL Command to retrieve data. Sth like select isnull(ColumnA,'1800-01-01') as ColumnA, C1, C2, ... Cn from Table
Make sure to use Isnull function for all columns with the datatype mentioned before.

2.Excute the SSIS pkg. It should work.

3.Go back to Control Flow, under the data flow task, add SQL Task control to replace the data back. I mean, update the ColumnA from '1800-01-01' to null again.

That works for me. In my situation, I cannot use ignore failure option. Because if I do, I will lose thousands rows of data.